# Gradle multi-module project does not run tests in one of the modules

Tags: gradle, junit, jacoco, multi-module

We have a Gradle 5.x multi-module project consisting of four modules written in Java and a plugin written in groovy. When the modules were in separate git repos, we had coverage for the plugin because the tests ran. With everything in one repo, it now no longer runs the groovy tests, yet it runs all of the Java tests. We've tried setting the classes directories explicitly in test {
    jacoco {
        includes = [dirs here...]
but it has no effect. There doesn't seem to be anything online about this problem. Has anyone seen it? If so, what's the fix?

Comment: If your Groovy tests are not executed at all, then this has nothing to do with JaCoCo.

Comment: could you provide any details of your gradle build and settings files?